# Average of Top 10 & bottom float_value, with date, group by date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, average, common-table-expression

I have a table like this:

```
| prodID  | date     |  perm
---------------------------------   
|200      |8/7/2011  | 81.742 
|200      |8/7/2011  | 81.644
|200      |8/7/2011  | 81.302
|200      |8/7/2011  | 81.057
|201      |8/7/2011  | 80.932
|201      |8/7/2011  | 80.839
|201      |8/7/2011  | 80.622
|201      |8/7/2011  | 80.557
|201      |8/7/2011  | 80.541
```

(except a bit bigger) 
Breakdown of what happens: I want to take the average of the top 10 values (and bottom 10 values) where a prodid = somevalue in this case 200.

Code:

```
declare @myid int
set @myid = 200

;with high as  --top ten average
(
 select prodid, CONVERT(CHAR(10),  DATEADD(DAY, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CONVERT    
(SMALLDATETIME, [date]))), 0),     101) as date, max(perm)as max_perm, avg(perm) 
as   
high_perm from   
( select prodid, date, perm, 
 row_number() over(partition by date order by perm desc) as nt    
 from live_pilot_plant
 where prodid = @myid) as T 
 where nt <= 10
 group by prodid
),
low as   -- bottom ten average
(
select prodid, CONVERT(CHAR(10),  DATEADD(DAY, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CONVERT    
(SMALLDATETIME, [date]))), 0),101) as date, min(perm) as min_perm, avg(perm) 
as low_perm  from   
( select prodid, date, perm,  
  row_number() over(partition by date order by perm asc) as nt    
  from live_pilot_plant
  where prodid = @myid) as T 
  where nt <= 10
  group by prodid
)

select l.prodid, l.date, l.low_perm as low_avg, m.high_perm as high_avg,
(m.high_perm -    l.low_perm) as delta
from low l
left outer join high m
on l.prodid = m.prodid
```

Which produces something like this:

```
|  prodID  |   date     |  low_avg   |  high_avg  |  delta   |
|   200    | 08/07/2011 |   68.752   |  79.1976   |  10.444  |
```

THESE NUMBERS ARE NOT ACCURATE --

This is all good and dandy - except not very versitle.  I mean there are a lot of prodID, and to do one this based on prodID is too slow.  How can I get the low_avg and the high_avg based on date (group by prodID)

Something like this:

```
| date       | prodID  | low_avg  | high_avg  |  delta  |
| 08/07/2011 | 200     |  60      |  80       |  20     |
| 08/07/2011 | 201     |  70      |  100      | 100     |
```

NOTE: You might have noticed a crazy convert infront of date.  The reason is that some prodID overlap dates ie. 200 on 8/7/2011, and 8/8/2011, and I need to average the date (which is a varchar). So something like if there were 100 rows with 8/7/2011, and then 9 rows with 8/8/2011, the final query would produce the date being as /8/7/2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query does it for all products at once:

```
select lpp.prod_id, lpp.date,
       AVG(case when seqnum_asc <= 10 then perm end) as avg_bottom10,
       AVG(case when seqnum_desc <= 10 then perm end) as avg_top10,
       (AVG(case when seqnum_desc <= 10 then perm end) - AVG(case when seqnum_asc <= 10 then perm end)) as delta
from (select lpp.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by prodid, date order by perm) as seqnum_asc,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by prodid, date order by perm desc) as seqnum_desc
      from live_pilot_plan lpp
     ) lpp
group by lpp.prod_id, lpp.ate
```

Comment: @GordanLinoff Where can I put my where date like '/7/8/2011'  This query is a bit hard for me to get at first glance

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you wanted it within a specific day.  I modified the query to include it in the partition clauses, the group by, and outer select.

Comment: @GordanLinoff -Holy smokes you're fast! Amazing..Thank you so much.